# Truth table of the next state function of a Moore machine

Tags: finite-sets

I'm studying finite state machines and trying to make this table but i don't know where to start. Isn't it necessary to know what happens when for example both inputs A and B from state s1 are active? The exercise in question doesn't say more, it just says to not consider the outputs, encode the states and inputs in binary, and that it's not necessary to describe the function for binary values of states and input not required by the diagram (?).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdCi0.png)

tried making a table, didn't succeed.

Comment: Those aren't multiple inputs labelled $A, B, \dots$. There is a single input with *value* $A, B, \dots$.

Comment: $A,B,\cdots$ are not distinct inputs, they are the different values that the input can take. So only one value is possible at a time and it triggers a single transition.